# How to choose the right setting of new photoshop document for a given purpose

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-quality, art, optimization

I'm using Photoshop CC, and it's working just fine.

I use it mostly for background images, for posters on social media and more and more for drawing these times. I also print some work from time to time.

When I set a new document, I'm always facing the problem of what setting is the best for this one.

How can I balance the size, resolution, color and other things when I begin a new document?

Is there a trick to get enough **quality** without using too much **disk space**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings should match the project needs.

I believe the biggest hurdle in the question is the issue of **disk space**. I don't think *any* project should *ever* be determined by how much "disk space" it will use. If you don't have much disk space, you may need to improve that. It's a mistake to limit yourself due to some constraint such as disk space. Hard drives are cheap.

This is akin to using acrylics to paint a portrait but you don't have any canvases, so you try and use an index card - you are merely doing yourself, and the work, a disservice.

---

For my work, I start everything as if it were ultimately destined for commercial printing. That means whatever dimensions are required, RGB (so filters work), and *always* 300ppi. This ensures I can always convert to CMYK if needed later and retain overall quality.

If nothing is ever commercially printed, then whatever dimensions you want at whatever PPI you want. It really doesn't matter. Although, I'd probably stick to something *consistent* such as 150PPI.

Comment: 300ppi does not mean much unless you have also a physical size to pair it up with.

Comment: I realize that joojaa.. but without project details it's impossible to state any type of "standard" physical dimensions.

Comment: @Scotti know you know. But by omitting the value your perpetuating the PPI as quality myth. If you can only see the other half of the thing you get confused. But your right this is how expers do use it but a lot of beginners get a distorted picture of what your doing

Comment: My biggest reason for *any* answer ot such and impossible question was.. disk space concern? In all my career that's *never* been a factor for anything. Whatever space a project needs, it uses. Even back in the days of floppy disks and 8MB of RAM `:)`

Comment: yeah i thought commenting on that but said to myself "not worth it". If somebody has their priorities this sideway i cant help them. But also we use computers for business a kid living with their parents may not have those resources for example.

Comment: @Scott Ok your point of vue kind of convinced me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The dialog is not qualitative. Resolution is the same thing as size (its just size per inch). The only thing that matters is how many pixels your image has.

Since on web publishing the dimension of pixels is mostlikely fixed for you none of the other settings really do anything for you. This fixes the disk usage and all otherthings dont affect your quality.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this question in detail since specific settings will very much depend on what the images are going to be used for, but here's some ***very*** general advice.

As a starting point, use one of the presets listed under the categories along the top of the New Document dialog. You can select a preset, then set a custom size, depending on what you want. Just leave everything else as is. Here's an example:

[image]

File size will depend on the final format you use for output. Save as JPEG for large photographic images on the web, PNG for small web graphics, maybe PDF for print work or PSD if you are importing into Illustrator or InDesign for further work.

Always remember to keep/save the PSD if you want to work on the image in future.

Comment: Thanks for your details, this help me too.